# Stuck on a simple probability question

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, binomial-distribution

I'm stuck on a probability question. I have a partial solution to the answer, but I can't get further.

The problem is as follows: consider a wine tasting experiment, we will ask our participant Bob to taste $N$ glasses of wine. Each glass is filled with either a cheap table wine or a grand cru, suppose there are exactly $k$ glasses of cheap wine.

Our participant Bob is a novice to wine tasting, so can not distinguish between the two types of drinks. We let Bob drink each glass and ask him whether it is a cheap wine or a grand cru. What is the probability of Bob correctly distinguishing $S$ cheap table wines, given that he does not know that there are k of them?

I think the solution to this problem is as follows: considering Bob does not know how many glasses are table wine and can't distinguish between the 2 types, the amount of times $L$ of him identifying a glass as table wine is binomially distributed with parameters $N, 0.5$. Now I suspect that the amount of correctly identified glasses of table wine $S$ is also binomially distributed with parameters $L, 0.5$. Because again, Bob can not distinguish between either wine. Is this correct?

Comment: He drinks all of them, so all N glasses. Should I edit the question to make this clearer?

Comment: Nope, it's fine as is!

Comment: Recall that a binomial experiment refers to the process of drawing elements **with replacement**, while a hypergeometric experiment refers to the process of drawing elements **without replacement**. Since you can only drink a glass once, the elements are clearly not replaced.

Comment: @MichaelR: It is not a   hypergeometric distribution. We aren't **drawing** without replacement, we are (in a sense) just randomly answering  a true or false test having questions of two types arranged arbitrarily.

Comment: @trueblueanil You're right. I misinterpreted the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We make the (only possible) assumption w/o any other data, viz. the probability of any glass being correctly identified is $0.5$, and we are asked to find out *Pr*($s$ table wines are correctly identified)

**Now it doesn't matter which glasses contain the table wine; for each glass of wine tasted (table or grand cru), the probability that he is correct will be 0.5**

So it should be clear that the pmf for table wine correctly identified will be $X\sim binom(k,0.5)$,
and although not asked for, that of grand cru will be $Y\sim binom(n-k,0.5)$
and pmf of **total** successes will be $Z\sim binom(n,0.5)$

So finally, $P(X=s) = \binom{k}{s}\cdot 0.5^s\cdot0.5^{k-s}$